# form validation fire on tab button click in jquery

Tags: jquery, twitter-bootstrap

I am using the following code

```
<div class="row">
    <div class="form-group col-lg-6">
        <label class="col-lg-3 control-label">Package Name</label>
        <div class="col-lg-9">
            <input type="text" class="form-control" name="packagename" placeholder="Enter package name" />
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

I am validating this textbox with jQuery code as

```
  $('#frmAddPackage')
        .formValidation({
            framework: 'bootstrap',
            icon: {
                valid: 'glyphicon glyphicon-ok',
                invalid: 'glyphicon glyphicon-remove',
                validating: 'glyphicon glyphicon-refresh'
            },
            fields: {
                'packagename': {
                    validators: {
                        notEmpty: {
                            message: 'The field required and cannot be empty'
                        },
                        stringLength: {
                            max: 45,
                            message: 'Package Name consists Maximum of 45 character length'
                        },
                    }
                }
```

In UI, when I press `tab` button this textbox getting validation.

How to remove the validation fire on tab button click?

I am getting this error in IE browser.

Comment: are you validating the form on document ready?

Comment: yes... @MancharyManchaary

Comment: Does this could help you e.preventdefault() ?

Comment: Fire a preventdefault on TAB click on an onblur call

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Bydefault, all validation plugin validate input when `focused` either by mouse click or keyboard <kbd>tab</kbd> and validation error triggered if selected element focus change while element(input) empty.

you need to disable the `live` validation feature which by default `enabled` so input don't get validate when focus changed from one element to another.

you have 2 options

```
live:'submitted', //<-- only validate when form submitted
live:'disabled', //<-- Disable the live validation
```

JS

```
$(document).ready(function() {
  $('#frmAddPackage')
    .formValidation({
      framework: 'bootstrap',
      live:'submitted',
      icon: {
        valid: 'glyphicon glyphicon-ok',
        invalid: 'glyphicon glyphicon-remove',
        validating: 'glyphicon glyphicon-refresh'
      },
      fields: {
        'packagename': {
          validators: {
            notEmpty: {
              message: 'The field required and cannot be empty'
            },
            stringLength: {
              max: 45,
              message: 'Package Name consists Maximum of 45 character length'
            },
          }
        }
      }
    });
});
```

[Fiddle Example Checked in IE](http://jsfiddle.net/wurg0wzv/3/)

**UPDATE** What you experiencing is known bug of `formValidation` in IE if input contains `placeholder`, so either remove `placeholder` or disable `live` validation

[Reference Link](https://github.com/formvalidation/support/issues/389)